# How to display one image after the other at regular intervals using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am learning JavaFX. I want to display some icons one by one after few seconds. My code is not working. I have written some code. and icons are stored in a separate folder called **images**.

```
public class Main extends Application {
  ImageView imv;   
  Scene scene;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primarystage) {
      gp=new GridPane();
      gp.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10));
      ...
      gp.setVgap(0);
      gp.setHgap(5);

      imv=new ImageView();

      // logic for displaying images

      scene=new Scene(gp, 450, 300, Color.TRANSPARENT);

      primarystage.setScene(scene);
      primarystage.setTitle("WINDOW");
      primarystage.show();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
  }
}
```

I couldn't find proper answers on web. I want to know the logic how it is done, what else I need to know. Because a single image I can easily display. But I don't know how to display multiple images one-by-one.

Comment: I don't know how much knowledge you have regarding Java or JavaFX. But you've to use Threads and Tasks to do this properly.

Comment: Oh, normally  can't do. I mean not possible with the traditional way?

Comment: I'm not telling you to go out of the box. You'll find a lot of content on Threading. But your problem is interesting I would like to give it a try. Give me some time.

Comment: I believe you're trying to make a slide show kind of program. Right ?

Comment: @Tanzeel, yes we can say so for now.

Comment: @Tanzeel Using a background thread for this is overkill. Much better to use an animation, such as `Timeline` or `PauseTransition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I've tried something for you. I don't know what exactly you're looking for but this code will give you some idea at least. I've made few assumptions. You've a folder under the same directory with the name *images* which has all your icons (to be displayed) as 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, and so on. I'm using Netbeans 8.2 which will automatically import necessary classes from the respective packages.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
...
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
...

public class Main extends Application {

  ImageView imv;
  Label label;
  String file="";

  GridPane gridPane;
  Scene scene;
  Task<Void> slideShow;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primarystage) {
    gridPane=new GridPane();
    gridPane.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 10, 10));

    // business logic for slide show 
    startSlideShow();

    imv=new ImageView();

    label = new Label();
    label.setGraphic(imv);   

    gridPane.add(label, 5, 0, 1, 1);      

    scene=new Scene(gridPane, 450, 300, Color.TRANSPARENT);

    primarystage.setScene(scene);
    primarystage.show();

    // spawning a new thread for this task
    new Thread(slideShow).start();
  }

  public void startSlideShow() {
    slideShow= new Task<Void>() {
      @Override
      protected Void call() {
        int i = 1;
        while (true) {
          try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            updateMessage(i + ".png");
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
          i++;
        }
      }
     };
     task1.messageProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
       Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/" + newValue));
       imv.setImage(image);
      });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      launch(args);
    }
}
```

Hope this will work You can customize the code according to your requirements.

Comment: let me try this solution.

Comment: Sure. Take your time!! :-)

Comment: It is working as expected after a small modification. Thanks a lot. I'll read more about Threads. :-)

Comment: Happy to help. All the best.

Comment: It would be easier and more appropriate to use an AnimationTimer here.

Comment: @mipa You're absolutely correct. :-) I'll try to do provide a better solution. Thanks for pointing out. I appreciate this.